# Java Regular Expression Remove Dummy Time Stamp

Tags: java, regex

I want to know regular expression will be most effective to achieve the following:

In a date and time stamp string, I want to remove the time stamp if it is just zeros. But the problem is the time stamp can have multiple formats. For example:

```
2013-02-04 00:00:00
2013-02-04 00:00:00.0
2013-02-04 00:00 AM
2013-02-04 00:00 PM
```

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Well what formats can it have *in your specific input data*? Do you have a complete list?

Comment: These are the only formats it can have.

Comment: I used replaceAll(" 00:00:00", ""). But it only works in case of the first format

Comment: @SairamSankaran. Can't you just remove the TimeStamp part using the `DateTime` library. You would specially like [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net). There you have got `DateMidnight`, which is set at `midnight`, only. And many more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line:

```
line.replaceAll("(00:?)+(.0)?\s*([AP]M)", "");

(              // start time group
00             // strange timestamp symbol
:?             // allow ':'
)+             // strange group can be repeated more than one time
(.0)?          // if ms was specified
\s*            // allow spaces before AM,PM
(              // AM, PM group
[AP]           // A or P letter
M              // M
)?             // AP, PM group can not exists
```

Comment: Thanks Taky. I am looking for something like this. So it is line.replaceAll("(00:?)+\s*([AP]M)?", ""); right? Will this work in case of the second format?